# Sentence Stucture

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, clauses

Would you explain the exact details of clauses between semicolons? Why do they exist? Is "that" followed by "in his work", a noun clause introducer and semicolons are separating and simultaneously joining some nouns, referring to noun clauses ?
The source of the text below is : https://www.nyu.edu/projects/ollman/docs/a_ch19.php

> First, the fact that labor is external to the worker, i.e., it does not belong to his essential being; that in his work, therefore, he does not affirm himself but denies himself, does not feel content but unhappy, does not develop freely his physical and mental energy but mortifies his body and ruins his mind.

Thanks for your beautiful and useful answers.

Comment: Don't assume that everything you come across, even when it appears to come from famous authors, will be an example of good or even acceptable English. This isn't.

Comment: I agree, I can barely comprehend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this text:

1. It's ideological claptrap. In fact it's Marxist claptrap, from Karl himself.
2. It's a translation from German.
3. The author admits that he's rearranged the thoughts in paraphrase.

All of these things lend themselves to confused and murky English. Notice, for instance, that we're given a "first", but no following, enumerated points. But let's look at the underlying structure. We're given a couple of alleged "facts". The word *fact* licenses a following relative clause with *that* to define the factual circumstance. Here we have two such clauses --

- that labor is external to the worker
- that in work, several bad things obtain

The two dependent clauses are separated a semicolon. It's hard to call this wrong, since punctuation is a matter of style, but it's an unfortunate choice because style guides often recommend that semicolons separate related *independent* clauses that aren't connected by a conjunction.

The second clause is itself a list of things, namely things that the worker does not do. He

1. does not affirm
2. does not feel content
3. does not develop freely

As is recommended by style guides, the list elements are separated by commas. But the author wishes to insert a definitional aside after *id est*, and if he set off that aside with commas, it would blur the distinction of the two dependent clauses and make it hard to separate the elements of the compound predicate of the second clause from the rest of the text.

Note that the two facts form a compound subject, so we're expecting a plural verb. But there's no predicate at all. We're not told what the two facts do or mean. The following sentence says

> The worker therefore only feels himself outside his work, and in his work feels outside himself.

Is your text supposed to be a dependent introductory clause: "Given the facts that ..., the worker only feels...."? Or is your text supposed to stand alone: "The facts are that...."? It's impossible to say without examining the original, and my German, being nonexistent, isn't up to it.

Here's a guess as to what a minimal, sensible change would look like:

> First, it is a fact that labor is external to the worker (i.e., it
>   does not belong to his essential being) and that in his work,
>   therefore, he does not affirm himself, but denies himself; does not
>   feel content, but unhappy; does not develop freely his physical and
>   mental energy, but mortifies his body and ruins his mind.

I have provided a predicate, parenthesized the aside, and explicitly conjoined the factual claims with *and*. I have preceded each contrasting element (after *but*) with a comma, and used semicolons to separate a list that has internal punctuation. Is this a faithful rendition of the original?

Who knows? It probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> First, the fact that labor is external to the worker, i.e., it does
>   not belong to his essential being; that in his work, therefore, he
>   does not affirm himself but denies himself, does not feel content but
>   unhappy, does not develop freely his physical and mental energy but
>   mortifies his body and ruins his mind.

Noun phrase [the noun phrase (introduced by "First") is used to start the sentence as a side remark, but it is essential to the meaning, and is further defined by the example]: *the fact that labor is external to the worker*, i.e. (for example), it (labor) does not belong to his essential being;

**therefore** = *because of that*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefore

The antecedent for *that* in the dependent clause is "labor"

"...that in his work, therefore..." = *because of labor in his work* / he
does not affirm himself but denies himself, does not feel content but
unhappy, does not develop freely his physical and mental energy but
mortifies his body and ruins his mind.

The main clause (in bold) and dependent clause (in italic) IS the example ["...worker, **i.e**, it..." to explain more about what the "fact" is:

**it does not belong to his essential being**; *that in his work, therefore, he
does not affirm himself but denies himself, does not feel content but
unhappy, does not develop freely his physical and mental energy but
mortifies his body and ruins his mind*.

The sentence expresses all ideas logically and clearly and is grammatically correct.

EDITED:

The sentence can be made into two sentences without changing the words or their order in the sentences: (subjects are italic and verbs are bold) [They would be in one paragraph, but for clarity I'll separate them.]

First, the fact that labor is external to the worker, i.e., *it* **does** not **belong** to his essential being.

That in his work, therefore, *he* **does** not **affirm** himself but **denies** himself, **does** not **feel** content but unhappy, **does** not **develop** freely his physical and mental energy but **mortifies** his body and **ruins** his mind. [The second sentence is using Compound Verbs (all the verb share the same subject)]

Comment: "Therefore" usually connects two independent clauses ,which is in contrast with what you said.

Comment: The semicolon, regardless of all modifiers or complements, connects the two independent clauses, and "therefore" is used as an adverb in your sentence, and is never, as an adverb, used to connect independent or dependent clauses. As for the dependent clauses, "therefore" is not a subordinating conjunction. I will edit my original comment leaving all the original wording in your sentence to show that you can take away the semicolon and still have two independent sentences.